# PHP class template in sublime text

Tags: php, sublimetext2, sublimetext3

In net beans you can quickly create templates for things like classes and assigned chunks of text to short cuts etc.

How can I do this in Sublime Text. I have looked around the net and can't find a simple example.

Comment: This is not a programming question..

Answer (score 1):

1) First of all make sure you have the correct syntax defined for the file you are working on (usually in the bottom right corner in sublime text).

2) Then be sure to have the cursor inside the `<?php ?>` tags.

3) Using your example of creating a class, simply start typing the keyword `class` and hit the tab or enter key to execute the existing, built-in snippet of sublime text.

4) You should see a basic code structure in your code now. Using the tab key again, you can jump through the snippet and adjust the parameters to your needs.

If you need more customized snippets, there is also the possibility of creating your own.
Go to `Tools -> New Snippet...` in the sublime menu. The syntax is difficult to describe, that's why I would recommend reading on about sublime snippets here:
http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/snippets.html

There are also many packages available for sublime that add extra snippets to your editor. Have a look here (be aware that you need Package Control installed): 
https://sublime.wbond.net/browse

Cheers! Hope this helps!

Comment: This doesn't work, the only 'snippets' available within Sublime Text (3) are lorem,tab and !env,tab